# delete dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have to write a program, where i use dynamic arrays:

```
int size=1;
double* dyn_arr = new double[size];

int n=0; 
double sum=0.0;
while(std::cin >> dyn_arr[n]){
    sum = sum + dyn_arr[n++];
    if(n==size){
        size*=2;
        double* new_array = new double[size];
        std::copy(dyn_arr, dyn_arr + n, new_array);
        delete[] dyn_arr;
        dyn_arr = new_array;
    }
}
```

I can't understand the part `dyn_arr = new_array` after `delete[] dyn_arr`. 
`dyn_arr` is a pointer on the first element of the array `dyn_arr`, isn't it? How can i delete the pointer/array and write again `dyn_arr = new_array` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. It seems like you showed how to do something in code and then asked how to do it. Umm .. with the code you showed. Is there some line of code whose function you don't understand?

Comment: after `delete[] dyn_arr` the array where `dyn_arr` pointed to is freed and `dyn_arr` is a dangling pointer. you can reassign to this pointer, e.g. `nullptr` or a pointer to another valid address like `new_array`

Comment: thank you, that was the question. I saw it in the theory part but i wanted to ask again for confirmation.

Comment: @Susliks, `double* dyn_arr` is a pointer. A pointer is a variable which holds a memory address. what `dyn_arr=new_array` does is set the memory address required to be a different one (which holds a bigger buffer).

Comment: `delete` does not delete *the variable* `dyn_arr`, if that's what's confusing you. It only affects the memory that the variable points to.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks (yes `delete` was the word that confused me :S )

Comment: C++ education advice: Don't expect too much from the course, if this is how C++ is taught. `delete[ ]` should be in a destructor, not in the same function as `new[ ]`. But there's already `std::vector`. so you shouldn't be reinventing dynamic arrays. `new[]` is a rare, primitive building block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dyn_arr` variable is a variable of type "pointer to double". That means it holds the address of a double and you can change which double it points to whenever you want.

```
double* dyn_arr = new double[size];
```

Now, `dyn_arr` points to the first of `size` doubles.

```
double* new_array = new double[size];
```

This creates a new variable of type "pointer to double" that points to the first of a new array of doubles.

```
delete[] dyn_arr;
```

This deletes the array of doubles `dyn_arr` points to. Since we got `dyn_arr`'s value from `new[]`, we can pass it to `delete[]` when we're done with the array. So now `dyn_arr` points to garbage and we mustn't use its value.

```
dyn_arr = new_array;
```

This changes the value of `dyn_arr` so it points to the new set of doubles we allocated. Since `dyn_arr` is a variable of pointer type, we can change it to point to different things whenever we want.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete[] dyn_arr;
```

You're not "deleting the pointer". You're "deleting" the memory that it used to point to. Now it points to nothing. It's dangling.

```
dyn_arr = new_array;
```

Now you're making the pointer point to the new block of memory, instead.

Answer (score 1):

`new_array` is a new dynamic array that was created inside your `if` statement. The lines in question are deleting the original array, and then assigning `dyn_array` to point to the new array.

```
delete[] dyn_arr;     // <--- Delete the old array.
dyn_arr = new_array;  // <--- Point dyn_arr at the newly allocated array.
```